# subgroup of a quotient group

Tags: group-theory

If $K\subset G$ is a normal subgroup of a group $G$, and if $H\supset K$ is a subgroup of $G$, then we have that $H/K$ is a subgroup of $G/K$. But I don't see how the elements of $H/K$ can be part of $G/K$ at all. For we have
$$
H/K \ni \bar h =\{a\in H\mid a^{-1}h\in K\}
$$
and
$$
G/K \ni \bar g =\{a\in G\mid a^{-1}g\in K \}.
$$
So it seems to me we can't have $H/K\subset G/K$, because the elements of $G/K$ actually contain elements of $H/K$, and aren't equal to it; $H/K\ni \bar a_{H/K}\subset \bar a_{G/K}\in G/K$.

But given that $H/K$ is considered a subgroup, it seems to me then that we would have an equality. Is this the case? Or am I confusing some definitions here.

Note: I don't want to use cosets here; just the definition of an element of $G/K$ or $H/K$ using the equivalence relation $a\equiv b$ iff $a^{-1}b\in K$.

Comment: Right, thanks, that helps. My definition of the elements of the quotient group should be equivalent to yours in terms of cosets, so while I see why $H/K\subset G/K$ thinking in terms of cosets, I still don't see where I made a mistake in my definition using the equivalence relation explicitly.

Comment: Check again the definitions. An element of $G/K$ let's say $gK$ for some $g\in G$ is the set $\{a\in G|a=gk, k\in K\}=\{a\in G|g^{-1}a\in K\}$.

Comment: @Test123 Isn't that essentially what I wrote down? It doesn't matter if we write $g^{-1}a\in K$ or $a^{-1}g\in K$. My problem is that if we write down how the elements in $H/K$ look like, it doesn't seem like we could be talking about the same elements, as these elements of $H/K$ seem to be a subset of the elements of $G/K4.

Comment: A typical element of $H/K$ is a coset $hK$ for some $h$ in $H$. A typical element of $G/K$ is a coset $gK$ for some $g$ in $G$. But $h$ in $H$ is also in $G$, so every element of $H/K$ is an element of $G/K$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I'm trying to find my error when I use the definition for an element of $G/K$ and $H/K$ using only the equivalence relation.

Comment: I think if you write out in detail what the various definitions amount in a simple case (say, $G$ cyclic of order 8, $H$ the subgroup of order 4, $K$ the subgroup of order 2), you will see what's going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $h\in H$. Then verify that we have 
$$\bar h\ =\ \{a\in H\mid a^{-1}h\in K\} \ =\ h^{-1}K$$
which is exactly the same set as $\bar h$ in $G/H$, that is, $\{a\in G\mid a^{-1}h\in K\}$.
To get more convinced, if $K$ is finite, both sets above have exactly $|K|$ elements, as $a\mapsto a^{-1}h$ is a bijection for fixed $h$.

A direct proof: with $h\in H$, assume $a\in G$ satisfies $a^{-1}h\in K$. 
Then, as $K\subseteq H$ is assumed, we have $a^{-1}h\in H$, so actually $a\in H$ must hold.

Comment: Thanks, I had completely forgotten the condition that $K\subset H$.